# Minecraft - Secret passage behind staircase?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have a hidden fortress built, and near the entry, you move down a staircase into the main reception area. At the bottom, I have the 2 middle steps and the row just above it also has 2 middle steps that are supposed to drop down and reveal a hidden passage behind it.

Here's my logic:

1. Flip the switch(lever)
2. First 2 pistons go down taking along the bottom 2 steps
3. Second 2 pistons go down, taking along the second pair of steps.
4. (This is where the problem is found) The last 2 pistons go down to drag down the second set of pistons which would also drag down the steps to an equal level as the bottom 2.

Now the problem there is it either drags down the 2 sticky pistons holding the steps without bringing the steps along, or it just doesn't drag anything at all...

Same problem goes for the other way around, it doesn't want to place the steps in the right places.

The area I have to make this work in is a limited 10(length)x7(width)x4(height) room.

Any solution would be welcomed, if needed, I'll e-mail you the world so you can view my current taking and maybe find a solution.

EDIT: Links to screenshots

The lever to "open" the staircase

[image: imageshack.us/photo/my-images/543/20121208013630.png/]

The staircase not opening so well, the rear 2 steps should drop 1 block lower

[image: imageshack.us/photo/my-images/841/20121208013639.png/]

The circuitry beneath the steps

[image: imageshack.us/photo/my-images/11/20121208013720.png/]

[image: imageshack.us/photo/my-images/138/20121208013725.png/]

Comment: Could you make screenshots this would help a lot in pinpointing the problem.

Comment: Last I knew, you can't string together sticky pistons to pull each other while remaining engaged with another block.  Have you tried shifting the stairs off to the side instead of down?

Comment: Sadly, there is no room to the sides and have to drag them down...

Comment: Andalur... As I'm a new user, I can not post images

Comment: You can post a link to an image

Comment: Couldn't post more than 2, so I removed the http:// part, just copy and paste though

Comment: Edited the images in, can't help with the problem though.

Comment: Thanks merlin, and np, seeing as it's half past 2 in the morning here, I'll go to bed and look for solutions later in the day.

Comment: I can't tell from the screenshots, did you implement proper [double extender](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Piston_circuits#Double_Extender) logic?  Pulling a sticky piston down doesn't also pull the block above it.

Comment: Thank you MBraedley, with a few modifications to the system they had, I was able to put it in a nice confined space beneath the staircase! And modify it for more stairs ofcourse.

Comment: @Hurly Since that seems to be the answer, can you post it as one? It's AOK to post answers to your own questions, here. Share your modified design with us so we can all use it! :)

Comment: I think the problem could lie in then fact that pistons act like they are 2 blocks tall, so if you power one diagonally above it, you can create a Block Update Detector (aka BUD), so if you power the bottom ones, power the top ones and then remove the power to the bottom ones, they will still be extended, because they are still powered. I think that because the top ones are powered and you try to unpower the bottom ones, they will remain extended, and there you have the situation that I can see in the second and third image.

Comment: You can actually string together 2 pistons in one way. Lets say A and B are the Pistons and C is the block. (A>B>C, Where > indicates Piston arm) First B retract C and A retract B. (AB_C) Then trigger a pulse to extend and retract B causing C to move down again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One construction I found that works reasonably well is to have the top staircase pull back instead of down, like so:

(Cutaway view)

[image: Closed position]
[image: Open position]

It's probably not as elegant as yours looks like it's aiming for, and it has to have a slightly sunken passageway, but hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to actually read this one, I eventually did sort it out and have it working well thanks to the double extender logic and a bit of adapting. but this would work just as well for having a lair that goes deeper instead of having a normal straight corridor behind a staircase.